# Unable to connect to mysql database using jsp page but below error java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jsp, html4

**Here is my code:**

```
 <%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
    <%@page import="java.io.File"%>
    <%@page import="java.io.InputStreamReader"%>
    <%@page import="java.net.URL"%>
    <%@page import="java.io.FileReader"%>
    <%@page import="java.io.BufferedReader"%>
    <%@page import="java.io.IOException"%>
    <%@page import="java.text.DateFormat"%>
    <%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.Arrays"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.Calendar"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
    <%@ page import ="javax.sql.*" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            try{    
                //Database Code
                java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prodnotification?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root","Rahulhi123"); 
                        Statement st= con.createStatement();
                if (null == con) {
                    System.out.println("Database Connection Error.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Database Connected.");//Database connection
                }
                }catch(SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            %>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is my code getting below error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prodnotification?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.apache.jsp.Home_jsp._jspService(Home_jsp.java:180)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1102)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:788)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1485)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: error code: 0 sqlstate: 08001

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed loading your database driver before creating the connection.
Also, Make sure the respective mysql jdbc driver's jar is placed in you classpath.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

As its a web project you should be placing the driver jar under `yourapp/WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Production_Notification] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /Home.jsp at line 40

Comment: at this line Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Comment: Have you added the mysql jdbc driver's jar in your classpath ? if not then you can find it here - http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: I have added the jdbc driver jar file in classpath.

Comment: can you test it now ?

Comment: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Production_Notification] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /Home.jsp at line 40

Comment: Kindly post the exception here

Comment: Unable to post the entire exception can you help new to stack overflow

Comment: Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1299)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1133)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:125)

Comment: I think its not able to locate the jar file. Have you placed it in the correct folder. As its a web project you should be placing it under yourapp/WEB-INF/lib